# In single page app, how do I determine when to discard a rendered section instead of hiding it to keep browser memory down?

Tags: backbone.js, single-page-application

I am migrating an enterprise WPF application to a web application. At this point leaning toward a single page app using ASP.net mvc3, backbone.js.

Really just hunting for best practices. The current WPF app allows for users to go back and forth between many tabs displaying lots of data.  I would like to replicate this functionality and am concerned with:

1. Will the amount of data in the DOM get too large for the browser to handle?
2. How do I deal with keeping that data up to date if the user is likely to have the app open for long periods of time?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've built several single page web apps using both Backbone.js and a proprietary MVC JS engine that is similar to Backbone. From that experience, I can tell you that there are no hard and fast rules, but if you look at the application as a hierarchy, it will help you define when you should destroy objects. For instance, in one of my applications, there are several modules, each related to a specific business problem or problem domain. My standing rule is that whenever the business problem changes, I will destroy the current module, then load the next. All navigation that is local to a module will simply hide and show.

In the current application that I'm working on, we have facility for making the application entirely a single-page web app, but instead decided to give the modules their own html files, so navigating to a different module will do a reload. To save on calls to the server, we bootstrap the most common data and that gets rendered into JS objects with the page. This is a hybrid approach that has worked well for us.